# Http request com angular 6

Tags: angular, rest, autenticação, http-headers

Estou tentando consumir um serviço REST que tem uma autenticação básica com angular 6 porém não estou conseguindo segue o código que estou utilizando sem sucesso:

```
public iniciarProcesso(dadosProcesso: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new Headers()

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=')

    return this.http.post(
        this.API,
        dadosProcesso,
        {headers: headers}
    ).pipe(map((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        return res
        })
    )
}
```

recebo como resposta:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/agendarEventoTeatro/start 401 (Unauthorized)

Failed to load http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/agendarEventoTeatro/start: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Alguém tem alguma luz de como fazer essa requisição?

OBS: Consegui fazer funcionar criando um arquivo de proxy no meu projeto e iniciando o node (ng serve) com --proxy solução (Gambiarra) retirada desse site
[https://medium.com/@gigioSouza/resolvendo-o-problema-do-cors-com-angular-2-e-o-angular-cli-7f7cb7aab3c2]
Minha dúvida é se publico meu projeto no servidor Apache ou outro qualquer será que vai funcionar essa "Gambiarra" em localhost funcionou de boa.

Comment: Ao que parece é seu server que está rejeitando a conexão, (ao que tudo indica por permissão) se puderes postar o controller do teu server aqui ficaria mais fácil de entender o problema

Comment: Não tenho acesso ao código do controler somente das configurações do servidor e web que no caso é o WildFly versão 8

Comment: Isso não é problema de angular, você ta fazendo um request e funciona, mas do outro lado tem um servidor que realiza autenticação e você não ta passando por ela porque tem um `'Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='` amarrado no código. Não é assim que funciona. Você precisa realizar um login e guardar o `Basic` em local storage para reutiliza-lo.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de como fazer isso  de guardar o login em local storage com angular

Answer (score -1):

Comecei a usar Angular 6 há pouco tempo mas nesse tipo de requisição uso geralmente dessa maneira:

```
func(objetoEnviado): Observable<TipoDoObjetoEnviado>{
    this.http.post<TipoDoObjetoEnviado>(linkDaApi, objetoEnviado)
}
```

Usando uma referência de tipo da variável enviada.
Não sei como está estruturada sua aplicação mas isso pode ajudar.

Comment: Então consigo consumir de boa outros serviços que não tenha implementado uma segurança, nesse caso em questão o serviço rest foi implementado com uma autenticaçõ básica que deve ser passada pelo cabeçalho mas não estou conseguindo, testei com postman e a conexão ocorreu com sucesso.